# JUnit not reading from same path as java static void main

Tags: java, junit

In my maven project I have a config file that holds various state variables and paths to resources. For instance I have this config property:

```
asice.root.folder=myapplication-validator/src/main/resources/asice/
```

When I run the program from static void main this resolves to the full correct  path:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Code\Projects\myapplication\myapplication-validator\src\main\resources\asice
```

However, when I run my JUnit tests the full path resolves to:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Code\Projects\myapplication\myapplication-validator\myapplication-validator\src\main\resources\asice
```

The java main and this test class is in the same module..

How can I set up my test classes to use same path as static void main? And why is another myapplication-validator added to the path?

Comment: Try adding a '/' to the start of asice.root.folder=myapplication-validator/src/main/resources/asice/ i.e. asice.root.folder=/myapplication-validator/src/main/resources/asice/

Comment: Maybe even './'

Comment: If you put something into resources directory you can resolve files by classpath.

Comment: Can you add some more code that shows how you read the value from the config in both cases? What type of project to you haven (plain-java, maven, gradle)?